# How do I make pillagers to stop spawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Yesterday I started a fresh world and after setting up a small base I saw a pillager outpost near it. Is there any way of getting them to stop respawning? I was thinking on simply destroying the actual outpost but I'm not sure that'll work, to be honest.

This is in the current version of Minecraft Java Edition (1.20.1)

[image: The Outpost]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only legitimate way is to replace all the grass and sand blocks and place torches so the light level is above 8.

Comment: Why did you repeat my answer ? That's not nice.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Pillagers mobs only spawn at light level of a block of 8 or lower. However, they’re able to spawn on Grass Blocks and Sand Blocks regardless of the light level.

So I would replace all grass blocks and place torches.

Comment: Did you test whether the block type actually matters? AFAIK only animals and Wither skeletons care about that. Also, please don't post two basically identical answers.

Comment: Yes, I tested it. And I did not answer twice because the conclusion doesn't include all the information about Pillager spawns.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the profile pictures look so similar, I thought it was both the same person!